# NodeJS Variable Sope in closure on concurrent requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, concurrency, scope

I am trying to understand how near-concurrent requests are handled in a NodeJS function that includes HTTP call in a closure.

In the example below, *sayHello* makes an HTTP request to another service.

If two near-concurrent calls are made to the function (1:name='Fred' and 2:name='Jane'), is it possible the re-assignment on line 3 could result in name='jane' being returned for both calls?

Since line 3 is in the closure processed at a subsequent tick after the HTTP event returns, could it's reference from the parent scope of line 1 have changed?

```
1  function (req, name, done) {
2    service.user.sayHello(name, function (err, status, body) {
3     name = name.toLowerCase();
4     return done(null, {firstName: name});
5   });
6  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each call to your function creates an entirely new set of local variables and function parameter variables so one call to that function has absolutely nothing to do with the next call to the same function again.

One thing you do have to be careful with is any referring to variables that are defined outside your function, but anything define inside your function is unique to its scope and unique to that execution of the function.

So, in this callback:

```
1  function (req, name, done) {
2    service.user.sayHello(name, function (err, status, body) {
3     name = name.toLowerCase();
4     return done(null, {firstName: name});
5   });
6  }
```

The variables `req`, `name`, `done`, `err`, `status` and `body` are all separate and unique variables each time this function is called.  Assigning to one of these as you are doing with `name = name.toLowerCase()` only affects this version of the `name` variable and not any other version that's created by calling this function again.

> If two near-concurrent calls are made to the function (1:name='Fred' and 2:name='Jane'), is it possible the re-assignment on line 3 could result in name='jane' being returned for both calls?

No.  The arguments to the function are unique and separate each time the function is called and one function call's arguments have nothing to do with the others.

> Since line 3 is in the closure processed at a subsequent tick after the HTTP event returns, could it's reference from the parent scope of line 1 have changed?

No, not unless your code inside this function changed it.  No outside code can get access to it.

---

There is one other thing to be aware of (that does not appear to be in play in this particular example).  When passing an object to a function, the object is passed as a pointer.  That means that if any other code might also be modifying that object while you're running asynchronous operations, then the object might be modified out from under you.  Here's a simple example:

```js
function delayIncrement(obj, t) {
    console.log(`${t} timer started, obj.cntr = ${obj.cntr} at entry`)
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(`${t} timer fired, obj.cntr = ${obj.cntr} before incr`);
        ++obj.cntr;
    }, t);
}

let sampleObj = {cntr: 1};

delayIncrement(sampleObj, 100);
delayIncrement(sampleObj, 50);
delayIncrement(sampleObj, 10);

// now example sampleObj a long time later after all timers have completed
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(`final result for sampleObj.cntr = ${sampleObj.cntr}`);
}, 1000);
```

In this example, sampleObj is passed to each `delayIncrement()` call and because it's an object, it is passed by pointer.  That means that when any of the `delayIncrement()` function calls modify any property of `sampleObj`, all the functions that it was passed as a pointer to will see that same modification.

This notion of pass by pointer in Javascript occurs only when passing objects.  When you pass a string or a number or boolean or any type that Javascript refers to as a primitive, then it is passed by value, not by pointer.  In your example, I'm assuming that `name` is a string so it is not subject to the issue that objects are.  Keep in mind that `{name: "Bob"}` is not the only type of object in Javsacript.  An array is also an object as is a `Map` or a `Set` and many other object types like this.  Javascript primitive types are `Boolean`, `Null`, `Undefined`, `Number`, `String`, `Symbol`.  More details [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response; that all makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You are only passing in one parameter 'name' for the function on line 1, so each function call would have a name variable passed as a parameter so you are referencing the name parameter not a name global object, each function call would have it's own scope in the stack queue. The fact that they are made near concurrently makes no difference they still have their own scope in the function you have written. The parameter 'name' only exists within the function call. So if two different function calls are made the parameter name is created two times and only exists in the scope of the call. So name === 'Fred' has it's own scope and name === 'Jane' has it's own scope on the stack queue.
So no, name = 'Fred' could never be name = 'Jane'.